# Best Practice Interpreting SQL Data with Switch/Case To Avoid Unnecessary Eloquent Calls

Tags: sql, laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm still new to Inertia/VUE3 & Laravel. I'm more familiar with PHP but I want to use best practices for what I'm doing here. I'm sure it's relatively simple so I appreciate all your help. I just wasn't sure what to search in looking for a solution.

I'm essentially creating a facade for a somewhat spaghetti ASP.NET app my company uses. There are several data points that are integers that point to another table for translation in their app. I do not want to recreate their database structure completely with Eloquent so I'd like to create a few functions on the model (I think that's what I need to do) to interpret some of this data being returned from my initial query for display. I'm wondering whether I should do this in my model, controller, or vue file.

In this example, the "StatusID" is an integer which is then translated to something like "Posted", "Cancelled", etc. I don't want to make a call to the DB just to get these translations.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\eRequester\Requisition;
use App\Models\eRequester\ProjectManager;

class RequisitionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Requisition/Index',[
                'requisitions' => Requisition::with(
                    'lines:RequisitionLineID,ItemID,Description,ProjectNumber,RequisitionID',
                    'owner:UserID,UserName,FirstName,LastName')
                    ->latest()
                    ->where('StatusID','!=','2')
                    ->limit(15)
                    ->select('RequisitionID','Title','UserID')
                    ->get(),
                'projectmanagers' => ProjectManager::where('AttributeID','siica3')
                    ->orWhere('AttributeID','ckwca7')
                    ->orWhere('AttributeID','orica3')
                    ->get(),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\eRequester\Requisition  $requisition
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Requisition $requisition)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\eRequester;

use App\Models\eRequester\ERequesterUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Requisition extends Model
{
    protected $connection = '{redacted}';
    protected $table = 'Requisition';
    protected $primaryKey = 'RequisitionID';
    const CREATED_AT = 'DateRequested';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'DateSubmitted';

    public function lines(){
        return $this->hasMany(RequisitionLine::class, 'RequisitionID');
    }

    public function owner(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ERequesterUser::class, 'UserID');
    }

}
```

**Vue**

```
<script setup>
import { Link, button } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

defineProps(['req','pm']);
</script>

<template>
    <div class="p-4 border-2 mb-4 rounded-lg">
        <div class="text-white font-bold uppercase flex justify-between">
            <span class="">
                
            <a target="_BLANK" :href="'https://[redacted]/req/review.aspx?reqid=' + req.RequisitionID">
                <button class="bg-white hover:bg-blue-200 text-black font-bold py-0 px-2 mr-2 mb-2 rounded transition-all">
                    {{ req.RequisitionID }}
                </button></a>
                    {{ req.Title }}
            </span>
            <span class="">
                {{ req.owner.FirstName}} {{req.owner.LastName}}
            </span>
            
        </div>
        <div v-for="line in req.lines" class="m-2"
            :key="line.RequisitionLineID"
            :line="line">
            {{ line.RequisitionLineID }}: {{ line.ItemID }} | {{ line.Description }} | {{ line.ProjectNumber }}
            </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried to translate at the controller level in my inertia render and also tried to translate via the model, but I know there's probably some really simple solution which I'm missing.

On my model I thought maybe I could use a public function, but I wasn't sure how to supply the data from the controller. I also wasn't sure whether this was the smartest way to do this. I'd like for it to use PHP as opposed to JS since it won't be changing and with a basic understanding of progressive enhancement.

```
public function status($statusID){
        // Translation switch/case
    }
```

I would like to be able to use PHP to translate some simple integer data into human-readable format.

Comment: I'm going to guess a little but, bit you're trying to make sense of `->where('StatusID','!=','2')`, correct? There are a couple of ways: 1) constants in the model. Quickly: `const Posted = 1;`, something like that. Then you have enums. In the enums you can add translations. There's also a package for Laravel with translations and everything. I would go for constants in the model, for now.

Comment: I'm most concerned about the display layer, rendering this translation in the inertia vue component so it reads as "Posted" instead of "7"

Comment: PHP is more comfortable to me, but I get confused when it comes to getting that server-side info into something I can display in Vue. I apologies for my n00biness

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://efbtechnology.com/define-constant-in-laravel/#:~:text=Laravel%20is%20most%20popular%20and%20full%20of%20features,is%20an%20example%20of%20order%20stage%20That%E2%80%99s%20it.

wher ethe constant is defined in the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use some sort of enum

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-enum

```php
// app/Enums/StatusEnum.php
enum StatusEnum: int
{
    case Posted = 1;
    case Cancelled = 2;
    case SomethingElse = 3;
}
```

```php
// app/Models/Requisition.php
class Requisition extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'statusID' => StatusEnum::class
    ];

    // $requisition->status->value === 1
    public function getStatusAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute('statusID');
    }

    // magic method to make `Requisition::whereStatus(StatusEnum::Posted)` work
    public function scopeWhereStatus($query, $value)
    {
        $query->where('statusId', $value);
    }

    // Requisition::with('...')->wherePosted()->latest()
    public function scopeWherePosted($query)
    {
        $query->where('statusId', StatusEnum::Posted);
    }
}
```

```php
Requisition::where('statusID', StatusEnum::Posted)
```

https://enversanli.medium.com/how-to-use-enums-with-laravel-9-d18f1ee35b56

Comment: My apologies for being uninitiated, but where would that first code block go, the definition of the class? Is that also on the model? Or is that it's own model?

Comment: Hi @rawslugs I was just curious where this piece goes, on the model? or its own model?i tried to figure it out in the link you posted but i'm kinda dense on Laravel. Still learning.

enum StatusEnum: int
{
    case Posted = 1;
    case Cancelled = 2;
    case SomethingElse = 3;
}

Comment: enums are a part of php https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.basics.php just treat it as a regular class

Comment: it seems like accessors were actually what I was looking for. Sweet and simple.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, it turns out that Accessors are what I was needing. I am able to define a constant on the model and then a function and appends to add the translation to the Eloquent query grab.

**Model**

```
  protected $appends = [
        'status',
    ];

    public const STATUS = [
        0 => "Incomplete",
        1 => "Unsubmitted",
        2 => "Cancelled",
        3 => "Rejected",
        4 => "Waiting",
        5 => "Request Info",
        6 => "Approved",
        7 => "Posted",
        8 => "Partially Received",
        9 => "Closed",
        10 => "Require Change",
        11 => "Resubmitted for Post Approval Routing",
        12 => "Edited (Post Approval)",
        13 => "Fully Received",
        14 => "Posted - On Hold"
    ];

...

 public function status(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::get(fn() => self::STATUS[ $this->attributes['StatusID']]);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
     return Inertia::render('Requisition/Index',[
                'requisitions' => Requisition::with(
                    'lines:RequisitionLineID,ItemID,Description,ProjectNumber,RequisitionID',
                    'owner:UserID,UserName,FirstName,LastName')
                    ->latest()
                    ->where('StatusID','!=','2')
                    ->limit(15)
                    ->select('RequisitionID','Title','UserID','StatusID')
                    ->get(),
                'projectmanagers' => ProjectManager::where('AttributeID','siica3')
                    ->orWhere('AttributeID','ckwca7')
                    ->orWhere('AttributeID','orica3')
                    ->get(),
                'companies' => [
                    ['CompanyID' => '3', 'CompanyName' => 'Spitzer'],
                    ['CompanyID' => '2', 'CompanyName' => 'Curtis Kelly'],
                    ['CompanyID' => '4', 'CompanyName' => 'Orizon']],
            ]);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone. Seems like enumerators are slightly phased out in favor of accessors & mutators.